# Manually fire bootstrap navbar menu click event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a requirement, where i have to manually fire click event of bootstrap(v3.3.5) navbar menu. I have tried click event of li as well as the  tag inside li, but they dint work. below is my code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="index.html"><span class="menuicon home"></span><span class="menutittle">Home</span></a></li>
        <li id="li_contact"><a href="contact.html"><span class="menuicon contact"></span><span class="menutittle">Contact</span></a></li>
        <li id="li_watsNew"><a href="wats-new.html"><span class="menuicon fingerprint"></span><span class="menutittle">What's New</span></a></li>

        /// etc. . . .
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#li_watsNew').click(); //doesn't fire
```

OR

```
$('#li_watsNew a').click(); //doesn't fire
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: hi vikas, try this $('#li_watsNew a').trigger('click');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code will take the user to the location that your `<a>` is pointing to:

```
window.location = $('#li_watsNew a').attr('href');
```

This one will also trigger onclick events:

```
$('#li_watsNew a')[0].click();
```

---

The problem with your code is, that it's using the jQuery's click event. In this case, you need the native one. The `$()[0]` of a jQuery object gives you it's DOM version (of the first query match). You could also use jQuery's `$().get(0)`, it's completely equivalent to `$()[0]`